# Howto import CAMT053 XML with CiviBanking

Tags: import

Is somebody importing CAMT053 XML from ING or another bank?

We want to import bank statements from ING, a Dutch bank.
ING can export to CSV, but that export does not contain postal adresses.
The CAMT053 XML does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the Belgian format. See https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/6dd79b42941eea6e89ba8e8b6475af418fddb2ad/configuration_database/importer/xml/BE_CAMT53_v2.json  . Some discussion about this file can be found at https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/issues/132 .

Comment: Am using that json now. Needed to customize it a littlebit to get the postal adresses. Also found out that the ING XML export which includes batch statements doesn't have postal adresses. Strange...